# Connect to SQL Server Analysis service through QlikView

Tags: sql-server, qlikview

I have a cube in SQL Server Analysis Service and I want to access this cube from QlikView.

How can I do this?

I don't want to write a MDX query in QlikView, I just want to have direct access to the cube from QlikView.

Comment: Qlikview is an in-memory solution - you would need to use an MDX query to load the data in. What I have done in the past is load the feeds going into SSAS directly into Qlik instead

Comment: Thank you Chris for your comment

Comment: Im pretty sure there is an SAS ODBC driver you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem some years ago, and developed a small tool that is available in http://xthview.com/. It allows to connect to a SSAS cube, select Measures and Dimensions as copy/paste the MDX query to QlikView.

Hope this helps!